# Dynamically add new typeAliases to hsqldb (inet and text)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hsqldb

I am working with hibernate and PostgreSQL for deployment and for testing I am using hsqldb. Is there a way that I can add aliases (without changing hsqldb source code) for types that are not hsqldb compatible (i.e inet and text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. HSQLDB 2.2 allows you to define new types.

- Use PostgreSQL syntax compatibility
  mode. This adds support for the TEXT
  type as well as several important
  syntax differences. Appending `;sql.syntax_pgs=true` to the end of URL or adding it as a connection property, or executing the SQL statement SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE enables the PostgreSQL syntax mode. The syntax additions are documented in the HSQLDB Guide here http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_compatibility_postgres
- Use `CREATE TYPE new_type_name AS
  built_in_type_definition` to create
  aliases for types that are not
  supported

Comment: How do I set hsqldb to Use PostgreSQL syntax compatibility mode ?